# Google Maps not appearing until refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using a google map on my website and when I navigate to my website [fly.multicrew.co.uk](http://fly.multicrew.co.uk) the area where my google map should be does not load until I refresh the page, in the console the error that comes up is `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at acarsmap.js:29` 
Here are the first few lines of my acarsmap.js file

```
var flightMarkers = [];
var routeMarkers = [];
var flightPath = null;
var depMarker = null, arrMarker = null;
var info_window= null;
var run_once = false;

var defaultOptions = {
autozoom: true,
zoom: 4,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.007739,9.580078),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
refreshTime: 12000,
autorefresh: true
};
var options = defaultOptions;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("acarsmap"), options);
```

Here is the code for the map on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
?>
var acars_map_defaults = {
    autozoom: true,
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo Config::Get('MAP_CENTER_LAT'); ?>", "<?php echo Config::Get('MAP_CENTER_LNG'); ?>"),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    refreshTime: 10000
};
</script>
```

Comment: it's possible you are trying to access the google object before the google object has been created by the google script - if the code you've shown is not in some callback function (for document ready, or the callback you can supply in the google script url) then google may well be undefined, but when you refresh the page, because the google script is cached, the google object is available by the time your code runs

Comment: @JaromandaX I've updated my post

Comment: well `center: new google.maps.LatLng` will only work after the google maps library is fully loaded ... your code doesn't wait for this eventuallity

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: go through the google maps examples

Comment: your problem could be related  with the way you initialize you map  and get the google maps library  ... you should add  also this part of code ..

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good with either php or JavaScript, I didnt make the map. How could I do this?